# Column-count does not split content on defined number of columns

Tags: css

I have a list which I want to split on columns.

```
<div class="newspaper">
  <ul>
    <li><span>eleemt 1</span>  
    <li><span>eleemt 2</span>  
    <li><span>eleemt 3</span>  
    <li><span>eleemt 4</span>   
    <li><span>eleemt 5</span>   
    <li><span>eleemt 6</span>          
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.newspaper ul {
    -webkit-column-count: 5;
    -moz-column-count: 5;
    column-count: 5;
}
```

Output is a bit different from what I expected (there are only 3 columns + spaces for 2 more).

[image]

Here is [my example with column-count on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dpastov/8tc917ur/)

**Questions:**

1. Is it normal behaviour?
2. Is it possible to change that behaviour, so I have 5 columns (or whatever number I specify)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Columns are filled vertically first.

So now that you have 6 elements but only five columns it means that one column will have two rows (*its height will increase to fit them*). But since all columns follow the same setup, once the height of a columns is increased, it is increased for all columns.

And since the fill vertically the first can fit 2, the second 2, the third 2, ...

It is the normal way columns work.

---

So you **do** have 5 columns, it is just that the last two are empty.

Comment: Thanks, that was very simple and informative explanation.

Answer (score 1):

It's because 5 is less than 6, and 6 isn't divisible by 5, as you have six entries. Add more entries, or change the column count -- it'll work properly then. See [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8tc917ur/1).

```
<div class="newspaper">
  <ul>
    <li>  
      <span>eleemt 1</span>  
    </li>
    <li>  
      <span>eleemt 2</span>  
    </li>
    <li>  
      <span>eleemt 3</span>  
    </li>
    <li>  
      <span>eleemt 4</span>  
    </li>
    <li>  
      <span>eleemt 5</span>  
    </li>
    <li>  
      <span>eleemt 6</span>  
    </li>
    <li>  
      <span>eleemt x</span>  
    </li>
    <li>  
      <span>eleemt x</span>  
    </li>
    <li>  
      <span>eleemt x</span>  
    </li>
    <li>  
      <span>eleemt x</span>  
    </li>
    <li>  
      <span>eleemt x</span>  
    </li>
    <li>  
      <span>eleemt x</span>  
    </li>
    <li>  
      <span>eleemt x</span>  
    </li>
    <li>  
      <span>eleemt x</span>  
    </li>
    <li>  
      <span>eleemt x</span>  
    </li>
    <li>  
      <span>eleemt x</span>  
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```